# OpenShift rolled back my deployment after restart application

Tags: openshift

I need help here. I just created an OpenShift WildFly 10 application and deployed a WAR file into it via web console. After deployment everything works fine. But after I restart the application with rhc command, my deployment was rolled back and only showing default main page just like after I created the new application.

Comment: Is this openshift online you are talking about? If so, can you access the server logs? Ref: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-log-files.html

Comment: I already checked the logs. It seems like my free cartridges will be reverted to initial deployment whenever the server sleeps.